# How to create a grid with back and forth navigation in QML for IOS

Tags: ios, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm new to QML Development. I would like to create a grid 10x2. When an element inside the grid is clicked, it takes me to the next page and show a back arrow button on toolbar to bring me back to the main grid page.

The result I'm searching for is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BltxC.jpg).

Comment: Please any body working on this type of Project can share with me

Comment: Downvoted. Welcome to stack overflow. That's not the way to ask for help. Question asking for tool, ready-made solutions or libraries are off topic. Show your effort in solving the specific issue and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can you the `visible` poperty of the element as follows:

```
Item {
    id: menu
    anchors {
        top: parent.top
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    Component {
        id: delegate
        Rectangle {
            id: wrapper
            width:
            height:
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    gView.currentIndex = index;
                    goAway();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    GridView {
        id: gView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: model    // your model
        delegate: delegate
        highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
        focus: true
        clip: true
    }
    function goAway() {
        gView.visible = false;
        arrow.visible = true;
    }

    function comeBack() {
        gView.visible = true;
        arrow.visible = false;
    }
    Image {
        id: arrow
        source:    //your arrow image source
        visible:false
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left
            leftMargin: 20
        }
        MouseArea {
             anchors.fill: parent
             onClicked: comeBack()
        }
}
```

You can edit it according to your needs.